# How to specify working directory for all subprojects by idea plugin?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl, subproject

There's a Gradle project with subprojects.

When add *idea* [plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/idea_plugin.html), the Gradle will start to generate Spring Boot configurations of Intellij Idea for each subproject.

The **issue** is that these Spring Boot configurations have the *working directory* of the **parent project**, not the current **sub-project**.

I found that I can set `$MODULE_DIR$` in the working directory manually via Intellij Idea UI. This fixed my issue!

How can this be automated?